# Middleware that save the user_id after request in adonis.js / node.js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have one table called job, this table contains:

```
job
--------------
id INTEGER PK,
name VARCHAR,
user_id INTEGER FK
```

I need to save in `user_id` the `user_id` that create the record.

Actually i make this middleware:

```
'use strict'

class Auditory{
  async handle ({ request, auth }, next) {

    const userLogged= await auth.getUser()
    const idUser= userLogged.id

    request.user_id = idUser


    await next()
  }
}

module.exports = Auditoria
```

I put one `console.log()` inside the Auditory class, so i know that this middleware is being called when i make a request, but the `user_id` is not setted in the request because is saving `user_id` null in database.

if i put a `console.log()` in `idUser` i get the correct `id` (3).

I'm forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

you try this may be it's work

```
Object.assign(request,{user_id:idUser})
```